# Is there a symbol for the "double gradient" of a vector?

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors

This is a really simple question, but I haven't found an answer anywhere.

The gradient of a vector $\vec{f}=<x(t),y(t),z(t)>$ is denoted by $\vec{\triangledown f}=<x'(t),y'(t),z'(t)>$.
Is there a symbol for the vector $<x''(t),y''(t),z''(t)>$?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what I would call a gradient. I'd call these ${\vec f}'(t)$ and $\vec f''(t)$.

Comment: Oh my mistake. It's been a while since calc 3. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is the derivative of a vector with respect to $t$. The gradient of $f(x,y,z)$ in cartesian coordinates is $$\nabla f = \left( \frac{\partial f} {\partial x} , \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} ,\frac{\partial f} {\partial z}  \right)$$

The thing that maybe you are asking for is the Laplacian, which depending on the book is written as $\nabla ^2 f$ or $\Delta f$ and, in cartesian coordinates, it is $$\nabla^2 f = \left( \frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial x ^2} , \frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial y^2} ,\frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial z^2}  \right)$$

Comment: This is an answer to mkspk's answer (apparently I can't comment because I don't have the required reputation): You are wrong. The Laplacian is scalar and is the sum of the double-derivatives: $$
\nabla^2 f = \frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial x ^2} + \frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial y^2} +\frac{\partial ^2 f} {\partial z^2} $$

Comment: Yeah, the "2" atop the Laplacian is a dot product not a composition like in most other places. It measures the divergence of the gradient.